# pass data from partial view to other partial view

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, partial-views

I have the partial view .cshtml page as

```
$("#btnsearch").click(function () {
    dserial = $("#dserial").val();
    $('.content').load("/ServiceMaintenance/SearchInstallationDeviceDetails");
})
```

Here "dserial" is the id of text box, "btnsearch" is the id of the button and "content" is the id[class] of a div to which the partial view is to be loaded.

My need is to assign the value of 'dserial' to a readonly textbox (let the id be "serialno") in the view SearchInstallationDeviceDetails.cshtml which is in the Controller "ServiceMaintenance"

Comment: Are you able to change the action parameters?  The easiest option is to pass the `dserial` value to the controller's action and have the partial view already have field read-only.   If not, then you just need to look at the `complete` param of `$.load`.  Let us know which you can do for a viable answer.

Comment: How can i store dserial  temporarly and that value is assigned to the textbox in other view.? @freedomn-m

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1 Change the action parameters, assuming a controller action:

```
public ActionResult SearchInstallationDeviceDetails()
```

change to

```
public ActionResult SearchInstallationDeviceDetails(string dserial)
```

(or `int`/`guid` if string is not appropriate)

then change your js to pass the parameter:

```
$('.content').load(
              "/ServiceMaintenance/SearchInstallationDeviceDetails",
              { dserial : dserial });
```

Note: this only works if it's a simple ID, if it's not a simple ID you'll have to use `POST`

then update your partial view's viewmodel to pass dserial and in the view:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model=>model.dserial, ...
```

---

> 2 Inject the value after the partial has loaded.

Not as nice, but depends on your restrictions (eg if you can't change the controller).  You might get a sort of FOUC (flash of unstyled content) - in this case 'un-entered'content

```
$('.content').load(
          "/ServiceMaintenance/SearchInstallationDeviceDetails",
          function() {
              $("#serialno").val(dserail).prop("readonly", true);
          });
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you fill it in after the content has loaded like this?

```
$('.content').load("/ServiceMaintenance/SearchInstallationDeviceDetails",
function() {
  $('.content #serialno').val(dserial);
});
```